# How can I setup and use a PostgreSQL database without installing a driver?

Tags: postgresql, odbc, ado.net, vba

I have a portable PostgreSQL database that runs perfectly on my computer as a database server. This is a work computer that I use for a lot of work in Excel with non-sensitive data (that is, data that is visible to anyone on the LAN).

Having access to a fast database server would make my life much easier, however, I need to be able to write to it using either VBA/VBS/Powershell or .NET. I can't install the ODBC driver for the database as that requires administrator privileges and I don't have a great relationship with the IT staff, so they would reject any request without even reading it.

Is there a way of inserting data quickly into PostgreSQL (or any other fast database server) without installing the driver? I'm thinking of something that functions as a portable driver. Since the database is run with only my privileges and I can insert into it directly form the command line, I am hoping there might some way of doing this from VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

postgres can be "installed" from a [ZIP file](https://www.enterprisedb.com/download-postgresql-binaries) by simply [extracting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881845/how-to-manually-configure-and-start-postgresql-on-windows) it.

[`psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) is part of the Postgres "installation" can be used without any further steps.

Any JDBC based query tool can also be used without "installing" a driver, as you can put the JDBC driver's .jar file anywhere you want.

It seems you can download the ODBC driver [binaries](https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/) directly without an installer. But I don't know if it's possible to properly register that with any tool that needs it.